# Think one word but type another word

Tags: words

I'm a writer so I'm typing all the time.
Recently I've had instances that when proofreading my work I discover that I typed a totally different word than the one I obviously intend, and that there is no phonetic similarity.
It's the kind of mistake that spell-checking can humorously cause. But I have turned off spellchecking. This is happening in my head, not the software.
Is there anything I can do to make this happen less often?

Comment: Alas, the Linguistics Stack Exchange is no place to seek clinical advice about your specific case.   How could strangers, even if they have the relevant credentials, hope to diagnose and treat you without ever seeing or hearing you? //  My advice?   Take your question to your physician.  Meanwhile, here on the Stack Exchange, you can ask questions about Linguistics, the science charged with explaining how natural languages work.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann As far as I can tell, the phenomenon the OP is experiencing is not as serious as you seem to have interpreted it to be (as far as his subjective experience is concerned) and he's simply asking for a psychological explanation rather than clinical advice.

Comment: When one is obsessed with words, it happens. (Not the clinical obsession). Example, one who is pre-occupied with the thought of 'bank' may write the intended word 'ban' as bank, which is just natural. What you could do is just to review before acting on it.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann You seem not to be aware of the discipline called "Psycholinguistics", alas!

Comment: @Nico:  The man's question doesn't address general issues in psycholinguistics;  it addresses his own tendency to type the wrong words.   That means that he wants clinical advice about his particular case, and that is something the Stack Exchange cannot give.

Comment: @ Nardog:   At the end of his post, the OP asks whether there is anything he can do to stop typing the wrong word.   That's a request for clinical advice--I say that as someone who recently retired from 30 years as a speech/language therapist.  Do you carry malpractice insurance?